# Git: How to apply just the latest commit from a branch?

Tags: git

I need to apply just the latest commit from another branch (call it `other-branch`) onto my current branch.  I could cherry-pick the commit based upon its ID, but this involves looking it up with `git log` (or similar) first and isn't a generic process.   How does one specify that they wish to cherry-pick *just* the latest commit on a specific branch?

Comment: You know, I actually downvoted and voted to close this question as "unclear" at first because it's so easily answerable from just googling ["git cherry pick"](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+cherry+pick), and it wasn't clear what your problem is (work on your problem statement). I removed the downvote and the close vote, but just for the record, I don't see this question and answer as particularly useful at all. Just "Read the Manual" `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake Question clarified accordingly. In order to ascertain a branch name is a valid revision specification, one needs to read at least 1.5 git man pages and learn the gitrevisions syntax.  I thought it useful to highlight that ``cherry-pick`` need not only use a hash ID as examples tend to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just cherry-pick the branch name as is:

```
git cherry-pick other-branch
```

This is because the branch name is already a symbolic ref name pointing to the given commit.

In the same vein, you could specify `other-branch^` for the next-to-last commit on the branch, or `other-branch~2` for the third-latest commit, and so on.  For more information about ways to spell commits, see [gitrevisions](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html).